# Making sure the user only inputs one of two words

Tags: c++

First of all I'm a beginner in c++. I want to allow the user to input the words "red" or "blue" and if they enter any other word/character/number, I want an error message or something like that to appear so that they can enter the words again.

Here is the bit I'm struggling with:

```
cin >> seedColor;
while (seedColor != "red" || "blue") {
    cout << "This is not a valid input. Please try again." << endl;
    cin >> seedColor;
}
```

When I try saying (seedColor != "red) everything works, but when I use the || operator, the program still runs, but every entry becomes invalid, including red.

Comment: You need to write `seedColor !=` twice...

Answer (score 5):

Because it's not how boolean expressions work. You need to write
`while(!(seedColor == "blue" || seedColor == "red"))`
for the behaviour you want.

Comment: I thought of the if statement first, but I need it to loop until the user inputs the right words. Is there no way to make it a loop? Also, thanks :)

Comment: That will work properly only supposed `seedColor` is declared as `std::string`.

Comment: Whatever works. I just thought it was if,  not while. Edited my answer

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ S/he wrote "When I try saying (seedColor != "red) everything works", so it seems to be a `std::string`.

Comment: I tried to declare my variable as std::string and it still does not work. This is incredibly frustrating.

Comment: @pkrysiak I've removed both my comment and my downvote as they don't make sense any more.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of your question isn't so complicated. There are many methods to do what you want.

If you want to make your method work, change while() content in:

```
    while (seedColor != "blue" && seedColor!="red"){
             //your sutuff
    }
```

In other words, first of all you need `&&` instead of `||` if you are using `!=` operator. If you were using `==` operator instead of `!=` in while, then you could use  `||` in your problem.

Secondly, you are not using fine `||` operator. You must have `logical_expression || logical_expression`.

Comment: That made a lot of sense. Thanks.